# Associating one swing component to another

Tags: java, swing

I am making a GUI utility that will allow to create a question paper through it. A question can have multiple parts. I have made a basic wireframe for this:[image]

My problem is that I can easily make text fields for questions and adding further questions, but how will I associate the parts of a question to it?  Basically I have a JSON array in the back end where a question will be stored along with its parts.

Comment: All stings that make a question can be stored in a collection. You can have a class that represents question-data where all strings forming a question are stored in a collection, say `ArrayList`. Better still this class, let's call it `QuestionModel` can be used by a `QuestionView` which represents the question view.

Comment: I understand that, but what I am asking is that when submit is clicked, how do we associate a part with its question

Comment: Suppose I have created two questions and four parts of each question, how do I differentiate be these two sets of question

Comment: Each `QuestionView` representing one question uses an instance of `QuestionModel` and stores all the information retrieved from the view in that model.

Comment: Would you please give a moment of yours to convey your answer in the form of a template. Had I understood it, I would have written a code also in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QuestionModel` represents question-data where all strings forming a question are stored in a collection. 
`QuestionView` represents a view of a single question. 
 
`Questionnaire` acts as a controller which also creates a dynamic view of  `QuestionView`s. 
For convenience the entire code can be copied into `Questionnaire.java` and run:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//Questionnaire acts as a controller which also creates a dynamic view of QuestionViews.
public class Questionnaire implements ChangeListener{

    private final List<QuestionView> questions;
    private final List<QuestionModel> questionModels;
    private JPanel questionPanel;
    private JFrame frame;

    Questionnaire() {
        questions = new ArrayList<>();
        questionModels = new ArrayList<>();
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        questionPanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(questionPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        questionPanel.setLayout(layout);
        addQuestion();

        JButton addQuestionButton = new JButton("Add Question");
        addQuestionButton.addActionListener(e->addQuestion());

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(e->collectQuestion());

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        buttonsPanel.add(addQuestionButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        buttonsPanel.add(submitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        mainPane.add(questionPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPane.add(buttonsPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(mainPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //adds a question to the questionnaire 
    private void addQuestion() {

        QuestionModel model = new QuestionModel();
        QuestionView view = new QuestionView(model);
        view.setListener(this);
        questions.add(view);
        questionModels.add(model);
        questionPanel.add(view.getView());
        refresh();
    }

    //refresh view whan something changed 
    void refresh(){
        frame.pack();
    }

    // ChangeListener implementation 
    @Override
    public void changed() {
        refresh();
    }

    //collect all strings from text fields and update models 
    private void collectQuestion() {

        for(QuestionView view : questions){
            view.collectQuestions();
        }

        //for testing
        printQuestions();
    }

    void printQuestions(){
        for(QuestionModel model : questionModels){
            System.out.println(model.getQuestion());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Questionnaire();
    }
}

//QuestionModel represents question-data where all strings forming a question are stored in a collection.
class QuestionModel {

    private final List<String> questionParts;

    QuestionModel() {
        questionParts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addQuestionPart(String text){
        questionParts.add(text);
    }

    List<String> getQuestionParts() {
        return questionParts;
    }

    //return the whole question as one string 
    String getQuestion(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String part : questionParts){
            sb.append(part).append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

//QuestionView represents a view of a single question
class QuestionView {

    private final List<TextField> questionPartsTf;
    private final JPanel tfPanel, mainPanel;
    private  ChangeListener listener;   //used to notify that view changed 
    private final QuestionModel model;

    QuestionView(QuestionModel model) {

        this.model = model;
        questionPartsTf = new ArrayList<>();

        tfPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 10));
        JLabel addLabel = new JLabel("Add question: ");
        tfPanel.add(addLabel);
        addTextField();

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add question part");
        addButton.addActionListener(e->addTextField());

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        mainPanel.add(tfPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
    }

    private void addTextField() {
        TextField tf= new TextField(15);
        tfPanel.add(tf);
        questionPartsTf.add(tf);
        if(listener != null){
            listener.changed();
        }
    }

    //collect all strings from text fields and update model
    void collectQuestions(){
        for(TextField tf : questionPartsTf){
            if(!tf.getText().isEmpty()){
                model.addQuestionPart(tf.getText());
            }
        }
    }

    JComponent getView(){
        return mainPanel;
    }

    void setListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}

//interface for listening to view changes 
interface ChangeListener{
    void changed();
}
```

Run it on line: https://repl.it/repls/VastNaiveModules

Comment: Thank you so much! It would help me greatly.

Comment: I am glad I could help

Comment: I've never received such a satisfying answer to my question anywhere. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to associate parts with questions.  Here's a plain Java class that holds one question and as many parts as needed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Question {

    private String question;

    private List<String> parts;

    public Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
        this.parts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public void addPart(String part) {
        this.parts.add(part);
    }

    public List<String> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

}
```

You would keep a List of Question instances in another class, your application model class.

As far as the view, you would create an additional JTextField each time the user clicks on the add parts JButton.  You associate those JTextFields with the parts in the Question class.